# KDB - CSV export doesn't work when running .bat via Task Scheduler

Tags: kdb

I have a .bat file to start KDB and run some code which then exports a table to a .csv.  I'd like to automate this task and have it run every night.  I've set it up via Task Scheduler to open and run the .bat file.

If I manually run the .bat file it will successfully save the .csv file.  However if I execute the .bat file through Task Scheduler it will open KDB and runs the code however the .csv file won't export.

I don't seem to be doing anything differently other than opening the .bat from Task Scheduler so I can't figure out why this won't work.

Anybody have any ideas or ways for me to debug?  Thanks!

Comment: Please post your bat file and save command; I tried an example and I was able to save it using the task scheduler

Comment: bat file -  <br/>  `set QHOME=C:\q
set QINIT=C:\q\servernightly.q
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\q\w32
q -p 9999`               `servernightly.q - DailyReport:`Sales xdesc delete Cost from update Margin:((Sales-Cost)%Sales)*100 from DailyReport2 where VendorID=`Total
save `DailyReport.csv`

Comment: I can't seem to get the formatting to work above.  I first have the bat file posted and then I have the q file where my kdb code is.  I have some other code in it however what I posted is the last part to create the table and then how I save the table (save `DailyReport.csv)

Comment: Also, the actions in task scheduler are (C:\q\startKdb32nightly.bat) I run it with highest privileges.  And this is what I see in the CMD prompt after it runs (C:\WINDOWS\system32>set QHOME=C:\q

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set QINIT=C:\q\servernightly.q

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set PATH=c:\q\w32

C:\WINDOWS\system32>q -p 9999
KDB+ 3.6 2018.05.17 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
w32/ 12()core 4095MB ks-man desktop- 10.0.1.192 NONEXPIRE

`DailyReport2
`:DailyReport.csv
q))

Comment: please add this code in the question, it will help others to understand your problem

Comment: q)) --> is suggesting it is some q issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following things and it seems working. however, I observed you are saving the file at the relative path which might be an issue as `Task Scheduler` launches it in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory. I am using an absolute path in the following code.

please give a try with this code.

**test.bat**

```
set QHOME=C:\q
set QINIT=C:\q\code\test.q
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\q\w32
q -p 9999
```

**test.q**

```
t:([] a: til 10;b: til 10)
save `$"C:/q/code/t.csv"
```

**Task Scheduler Action**

```
C:\q\code\test.bat
```

Comment: I think that fixed it.  If I manually execute through Task Scheduler it is now working where it didn't before.  The true test will be tonight when it runs by itself to make sure everything works.  Assuming it works tonight I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks a lot!